# It's possible to create envelopes for combinations of mark correlations with spatstat , generated from markcrosscorr?

Tags: r, spatstat

I would like to know if it is possible to create envelopes for combinations of mark correlations with spatstat , generated from `markcrosscorr`.

In the example on page 645 of the book (2015), I saw that it is possible from the `markcorr` command, which generates an object of the type `fv`. However, when I try to do it in a similar way using `markcrosscorr`, the following message appears: "`Error in envelopeEngine(X = X, fun = fun, simul = simrecipe, nsim = nsim, : The function 'fun' must return an object of class 'fv`'". Which makes sense, because markcrosscorr generates a `fasp` (array) object.

Another complementary question is, how to analyze the behavior of marks in cases of inhomogeneous marks patterns? Knowing that the mark correlation function considers that the distribution pattern of marks is homogeneous, would it be incorrect to use it to analyze such marks, since some behaviors could be generated by variations in intensity in certain spatial scales? I'm looking for the smartest way to parse my data marks as there are so many (both categorical and numeric).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If possible please make a reproducible example and provide more details about your data that you say is inhomogeneous and with many marks.

Comment: I am going to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command `envelopeArray` instead of `envelope`.

Example:

```
plot(envelopeArray(amacrine, markcrosscorr, nsim=9))
```